# apache http server changes for angular deployment

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to deploy an angular application in apache http server. To fix the 404 error on reload, I tried configuring the server as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

1. I created a folder in htdocs directory and copied the angular build files to it.
2. Created a .htaccess file under the same folder and added the below lines to it

> RewriteEngine On
>
> ```
> # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
>
> # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
> ```
>
> RewriteRule ^ /index.html

3. Started the apache server.

Now I tried reloading the page from the browser and I still get 404 error.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this content in your .htaccess file and put in your project direcory,

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Make sure you have properly configured your document root in http configuration file for your directory.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to configure document root in http configuration file?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Depending on your OS, locate the configuration file named `httpd.conf`. In the file, there will be a line starting with `DocumentRoot`. Set the path to the project directory. Its better to look up a video for getting the steps clear or you may miss something.

Comment: Sure but What if I deploy multiple angular applications running in the same Apache instance?

Comment: In that case, set the root as `htdocs` folder and put `.htaccess` in it. After that you can deploy multiple applications in different folders and access them by your <hostname+foldername> as URL.